# How to export Ionic Storage data into a file?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm designing a mobile app and I'll be using Ionic. I will store user's data in their storage. In the case they want to export their data to another smartphone, I was planning to incorporate an «export» and an «import» buttons so they could generate a file with their stored data and then import it using that file in another device.

For storage I was thinking about using Ionic Storage, as I saw it was the most popular solution. I could iterate through its entries while building the file. However, I was wondering if there could be any better solution, as I think what I'm trying to do is not that weird.

Comment: you can create a JSON file or CSV file to export and Save that file in users device. and they can upload it again to other Device.

Comment: Is there a code example how to create a JSON or CSV file from LocalStorage in ionic?